# How can I mark/highlight duplicate lines in VI editor?

Tags: vim, duplicates

How would you go about marking all of the lines in a buffer that are exact duplicates of other lines?  By marking them, I mean highlighting them or adding a character or something.  I want to retain the order of the lines in the buffer.

**Before:**

```
foo
bar
foo
baz
```

**After:**

```
foo*
bar
foo*
baz
```

Answer (score 120, accepted):

As an ex one-liner:

```
:syn clear Repeat | g/^\(.*\)\n\ze\%(.*\n\)*\1$/exe 'syn match Repeat "^' . escape(getline('.'), '".\^$*[]') . '$"' | nohlsearch
```

This uses the `Repeat` group to highlight the repeated lines.

Breaking it down:

- `syn clear Repeat` :: remove any previously found repeats
- `g/^\(.*\)\n\ze\%(.*\n\)*\1$/` :: for any line that is repeated later in the file

  - the regex

    - `^\(.*\)\n` :: a full line
    - `\ze` :: end of match - verify the rest of the pattern, but don't consume the matched text (positive lookahead)
    - `\%(.*\n\)*` :: any number of full lines
    - `\1$` :: a full line repeat of the matched full line
  - `exe 'syn match Repeat "^' . escape(getline('.'), '".\^$*[]') . '$"'` :: add full lines that match this to the `Repeat` syntax group

    - `exe` :: execute the given string as an ex command
    - `getline('.')` :: the contents of the current line matched by `g//`
    - `escape(..., '".\^$*[]')` :: escape the given characters with backslashes to make a legit regex
    - `syn match Repeat "^...$"` :: add the given string to the `Repeat` syntax group
- `nohlsearch` :: remove highlighting from the search done for `g//`

Justin's non-regex method is probably faster:

```
function! HighlightRepeats() range
  let lineCounts = {}
  let lineNum = a:firstline
  while lineNum <= a:lastline
    let lineText = getline(lineNum)
    if lineText != ""
      let lineCounts[lineText] = (has_key(lineCounts, lineText) ? lineCounts[lineText] : 0) + 1
    endif
    let lineNum = lineNum + 1
  endwhile
  exe 'syn clear Repeat'
  for lineText in keys(lineCounts)
    if lineCounts[lineText] >= 2
      exe 'syn match Repeat "^' . escape(lineText, '".\^$*[]') . '$"'
    endif
  endfor
endfunction

command! -range=% HighlightRepeats <line1>,<line2>call HighlightRepeats()
```

Comment: i can't get this to work. i've put the function in my ~/.vimrc but when i run ":call HighlightRepeats()" i get an error: Error detected while processing function HighlightRepeats:
line   10:
E28: No such highlight group name: Repeat

Comment: Daps0l: try adding `hi link Repeat Statement` to your `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: (it's probably because your colorscheme doesn't define the `Repeat` highlighting group)

Comment: this is probably a dumb question, but how do I clear the highlighting, it changes the color of the duped lines, but I can't get it back

Comment: if anyone else has the above problem, just use `:e` to clear it

Comment: What if I want to replace the duplicate lines instead of highlighting them?

Comment: I think there is a missing backslash: `\%(.*\n\)*` should be `\%\(.*\n\)*`
I cannot edit the response.

Comment: @jabellcu - nope, `\%(` ... `\)` is how to do [non-capturing grouping in vi regex](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%25%28)

Answer (score 85):

None of the answers above worked for me so this is what I do:

1. Sort the file using `:sort`
2. Execute command `:g/^\(.*\)$\n\1$/p`

Comment: Thank you. I feel this is better approach. With this we can find duplicates lines as well customize up to required length

Comment: I love how simple this is!

Comment: I'm going to need a hand with the explanation.

`g` global command (run through each line from top to bottom in this case)

`^\(.*\)$` capture the entire line ...

`\n` and the `newline` character ...

`\1$` and the previous line (to the end)

This part just checks if the next line is the same as the current line.

But why does my Vim highlight multiple separate occurrences, and what is the `p` (paste) for?

Comment: @Ari: `p` is for "print". Actually you can remove that, because it is the default command. Not sure what you mean with "why does my Vim highlight multiple separate occurrences". Vim should highlight/print duplicate lines.

Comment: Tried using `vim -u NONE` and it opens a split pane with the results. I understand what you mean by `print` in this context.

One of my plugins shows this https://imgur.com/a/6Qu8Q65 with highlighted rows.

On my other Vim instance it didn't show the bottom split and only highlighted rows instead.

Comment: @Ari my Vim is also opening a pane for the results. Not sure why. I'm unfortunately not an expert in configuring Vim.

Answer (score 20):

1. `:sort` and save it in `file1`.
2. `:sort u` and save it in `file2`.
3. `gvimdiff` or `tkdiff` the two files.

Answer (score 5):

Why not use:

```
V*
```

in normal mode.

It simply searches all matches of current line, thus highlighting them (if the setting is enabled, which I think it's the default)
Besides, you can then use

```
n
```

To navigate through the matches

Comment: Visual mode doesn't support * by default. It's probably a function you have in your .vimrc. Something like this:

xno * :<c-u>cal<SID>VisualSearch()<cr>/<cr>
xno # :<c-u>cal<SID>VisualSearch()<cr>?<cr>

fun! s:VisualSearch()
  let old = @" | norm! gvy
  let @/ = '\V'.substitute(escape(@", '\'), '\n', '\\n', 'g')
  let @" = old
endf)

Comment: Arg, the formatting messed up. Here's what I meant: http://pastebin.com/f2ee37c92

Comment: It would only match one thing at a time, whereas I'd prefer to indicate all lines that are duplicates of other lines all at once.  Nice function though, seems handy.

Answer (score 2):

Run through the list once, make a map of each string and how many times it occurs. Loop through it again, and append your * to any string that has a value of more than one in the map.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
:%s:^\(.\+\)\n\1:\1*\r\1:
```

Hope this works.

Update: next try.

```
:%s:^\(.\+\)$\(\_.\+\)^\1$:\1\r\2\r\1*:
```

Comment: This will only detect adjacent duplicate lines, and will only mark the first copy, not the second.