# How to highlight adjacent duplicate lines

Tags: vim

Is there a way to highlight duplicate lines in Vim, in a file, BUT only if they're *adjacent* to each other, i.e. if there is a line (in line 1) and there is a duplicate of that line (in line 99), do not highlight that.

But if there is a line in (line n), and there is a duplicate of that line in lines (either, n-1 or n+1) highlight those (or just duplicates).

*Is it something regex can accomplish?*

(this is waaay off my regex skills)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
:set hls
/^\(.*\)\n\1$
```

Comment: Yup, that's it :) Know I'm a pain, but is there a way to highlight only the duplicates?

Comment: @Idigas for that one I'd recommend to modify the function defined in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1270689/11621

Comment: Ah, excellent - that's exactly what I was looking for (the other answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following custom match pattern.

```
:match Conceal /^\(.*\)\n\%(\1\n\)\+/
```

Use

```
:match none
```

to disable previously defined highlighting.