# In Vim, how to remove all lines that are duplicate somewhere

Tags: vim, ex

I have a file that contains lines as follows:

```
one one
one one
two two two
one one
three three
one one
three three
four
```

I want to remove all occurrences of the duplicate lines from the file and leave only the non-duplicate lines. So, in the example above, the result should be:

```
two two two
four
```

I saw [this answer to a similar looking question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1270689/1806553). I tried to modify the ex one-liner as given below:

```
:syn clear Repeat | g/^\(.*\)\n\ze\%(.*\n\)*\1$/exe 'syn match Repeat "^' . escape(getline ('.'), '".\^$*[]') . '$"' | d
```

But it does not remove all occurrences of the duplicate lines, it removes only some occurrences.

How can I do this in vim? or specifically How can I do this with ex in vim?

To clarify, I am not looking for `sort u`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My [PatternsOnText plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4602) version 1.30 now has a

```
:DeleteAllDuplicateLinesIgnoring
```

command. Without any arguments, it'll work as outlined in your question.

Answer (score 6):

If you have access to UNIX-style commands, you could do:

```
:%!sort | uniq -u
```

The `-u` option to the `uniq` command performs the task you require.  From the `uniq` command's help text:

```
   -u, --unique
          only print unique lines
```

I should note however that this answer assumes that you don't mind that the output doesn't match any sort order that your input file might have already.

Comment: Ah, sorry, missed that (would have been nice if the answer highlighted that)!

Comment: but it sorts the input.

Comment: OK. If the original order is important then any solution that uses `uniq` won't work because it relies on the input being pre-sorted to get the behaviour you need.

Answer (score 3):

if you are on linux box with awk available, this line works for your needs:

```
:%!awk '{a[$0]++}END{for(x in a)if(a[x]==1)print x}'
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are on an UNIX derivative, the command below should do what you want:

```
:sort | %!uniq -u
```

`uniq` only works on sorted lines so we must sort them first with Vim's buit-in `:sort` command to save some typing (it works on the whole buffer by default so we don't need to pass it a range and it's a built-in command so we don't need the `!`).

Then we filter the whole buffer through `uniq -u`.

Comment: Ah, sorry, missed that (would have been nice if the answer highlighted that)!

Answer (score 1):

It does not preserve the order of the remaining lines, but this seems to work:

```
:sort|%s/^\(.*\)\n\%(\1\n\)\+//
```

(This version is @Peter Rincker's idea, with a little correction from me.)  On vim 7.3, the following even shorter version works:

```
:sort | %s/^\(.*\n\)\1\+//
```

Unfortunately, due to differences between the regular-expression engines, this no longer works in vim 7.4 (including patches 1-52).

Comment: A bit short: `:sort|%s/\(.*\)\n\%(\1\n\)\+//`

Comment: Very nice, and quite different.  I might even delete my answer if you post yours separately.  But anchor your pattern with `^` before `\(.*\)` or else "a four" and "four" may sort to adjacent lines and be deleted.  And you can make it a little simpler by capturing the `\n`:  `:sort|s/^\(.*\n\)\1\+//` (since `\1` is an atom).

Comment: I missed that anchor. Good catch! Your second substitution is made much tidier by enlarging the capture group. However there is one problem: It doesnt work correctly with Vim's new NFA regex engine (as of 7.4). `%s/\%#=2^\(.*\n\)\1\+//`. Feel free to post this answer in my stead

Answer (score 0):

Taking the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1270689/813602) and modifying it to delete the lines instead of highlighting them, you'll get this:

```
function! DeleteDuplicateLines() range
  let lineCounts = {}
  let lineNum = a:firstline
  while lineNum <= a:lastline
    let lineText = getline(lineNum)
    if lineText != ""
        if has_key(lineCounts, lineText)
            execute lineNum . 'delete _'
            if lineCounts[lineText] > 0
              execute lineCounts[lineText] . 'delete _'
              let lineCounts[lineText] = 0
              let lineNum -= 1
            endif
        else
            let lineCounts[lineText] =  lineNum
            let lineNum += 1
        endif
    else
      let lineNum += 1
    endif
  endwhile
endfunction

command! -range=% DeleteDuplicateLines <line1>,<line2>call DeleteDuplicateLines()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not any simpler than @Ingo Karkat's answer, but it is a little more flexible.  Like that answer, this leaves the remaining lines in the original order.

```
function! RepeatedLines(...)
  let first = a:0 ? a:1 : 1
  let last = (a:0 > 1) ? a:2 : line('$')
  let lines = []
  for line in range(first, last - 1)
    if index(lines, line) != -1
      continue
    endif
    let newlines = []
    let text = escape(getline(line), '\')
    execute 'silent' (line + 1) ',' last
      \ 'g/\V' . text . '/call add(newlines, line("."))'
    if !empty(newlines)
      call add(lines, line)
      call extend(lines, newlines)
    endif
  endfor
  return sort(lines)
endfun
:for x in reverse(RepeatedLines()) | execute x 'd' | endfor
```

A few notes:

1. My function accepts arguments instead of handling a range.  It defaults to the entire buffer.
2. This illustrates some of the functions for manipulating lists.  `:help list-functions`
3. I use `/\V` (very no magic) so the only character I need to escape in a search pattern is the backslash itself.  `:help /\V`

Comment: If you want to make a command out of it, then `:command! -range=% DeleteDuplicateLines for x in reverse(RepeatedLines(<line1>,<line2>)) <Bar> execute x 'd' <Bar> endfor` should work.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add line number so that you can restore the order before sort
   :%s/^/=printf("%d ", line("."))/g
2. sort
   :sort /^\d+/
3. Remove duplicate lines
   :%s/^(\d+ )(.*)\n(\d+ \2\n)+//g
4. Restore order
   :sort
5. Remove line number added in #1
   :%s/^\d+ //g

Answer (score -1):

please use perl ,perl can do it easily !

```
use strict;use warnings;use diagnostics;
#read input file
open(File1,'<input.txt') or die "can not open file:$!\n";my @data1=<File1>;close(File1);
#save row and count number of row in hash 
my %rownum;
foreach my $line1 (@data1)
{ 
    if (exists($rownum{$line1}))
    { 
        $rownum{$line1}++;
    }
    else
    {
        $rownum{$line1}=1;
    }
}
#if number of row in hash =1 print it
open(File2,'>output.txt') or die "can not open file:$!\n";
foreach my $line1 (@data1)
{ 
    if($rownum{$line1}==1)
    { 
        print File2 $line1;
    }
}
close(File2);
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I have provide my perl code here now,it is easy to understand