# More detailed advice on advanced mapping

Tags: vim, dictionary

I've found substantial use for commands that will find differences in two lists of words, and the best (and really only) solution to this I've found is this command:

```
g/^/kl |if search('^'.escape(getline('.'),'\.*[]^$/').'$','bW') |'ld
```

I want to make a mapping in my _vimrc file that will execute this line whenever I hit F2 for example, but I haven't been able to make it work.
If someone could explain character by character what this line actually does, I think it would make all the difference in the world. I've seen a dozen or so articles on vim mapping and none of them explain what things like `/` or `^` or `\.*{}^$/'` do in contexts like this one.

When are : needed in mappings? I've seen some examples with and most without.

When is `<CR>` needed?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a job for Awk

```
:%!awk '!a[$0]{a[$0]=1;print}'
```

However you asking a two questions:

1. What does `:g/^/kl |if search('^'.escape(getline('.'),'\.*[]^$/').'$','bW') |'ld` do?
2. How can I make a mapping to this?

#### The Mapping

Let's start with "How can I make a mapping to this?":

```
:nnoremap <f2> :g/^/kl<bar>if search('^'.escape(getline('.'),'\.*[]^$/').'$','bW')<bar>'ld<cr>
```

The trick is to use `<bar>` instead of `|` and to actually execute the command with `<cr>`. See `:h keycodes`.

#### What does this do?

It goes over every line of the buffer with `:g/^/` and deletes lines that are the same as a line from above, `if search('^'.escape(getline('.'),'\.*[]^$/').'$','bW')` and `d`. The confusing parts to me are the following:

- Using marks needlessly i.e. `:k` and range with the `:d` command.
- A complicated building of the regex for the `search()` function. By using the `\V` (`very nomagic`) we can reduce the line noise in the regex: `'\V\^'.escape(getline('.'),'\').'\$'`
- **Why** are you doing an `O(N^2)` operation when you can do an `O(N)`?

#### Simplify the command

```
g/^/if search('\V\^'.escape(getline('.'),'\').'\$','bWn') | d | endif
```

We remove the needless marks and simplify the escaping. I also added the `endif` to show the end of the if statement (this can be optionally left off because it will be assumed).

- `:g/{pat}/{cmd}` The `:global` command runs `{cmd}` on ever line matching `{pat}`
- `:g/^/` is a common idiom to run a command on every line, since all lins have a beginning, `^`.
- `if {expr} | {cmds} | endif`. Execute `{cmds}` if the expression, `{expr}`, evaluates to true
- `search({pat}, {flags})` search for `{pat}` in the buffer. `{flag}` alter the search behavior
- `search()` returns the line number of a match or 0 for no match found
- `b` flag for `search()` means search backwards
- `W` flag means do not wrap around the buffer when searching
- `n` do not move the cursor
- `escape({str}, {chars})` escape `{chars}` with `\`
- `\V` pattern uses very no magic meaning all regex meta characters need to be escaped
- `\^` and `\$` are escaped for start and end of line because of `\V` option
- `:delete` or `:d` for short delete the current line

I suggest you use the awk solution at the start of this answer.

```
:nnoremap <f2> :%!awk '!a[$0]{a[$0]=1;print}'<cr>
```

For more help see the following:

```
:h :range!
:h :g
:h :d
:h :l
:h :if
:h search(
:h escape(
:h /\V
```

Comment: Good use of `\V`.  If you want an `O(N)` solution that does not rely on awk (for example, you want it to work even if vim is running on a crippled OS) then it would be easy to modify the function I gave here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/22202004/3130080

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I added both mappings to $MYVIMRC (under <f2> and <f3>) and the second one doesn't work for me. It says no previous command.
I'm not new to programming, but I am new to vim and linux so I'm still confused about many of the operators and I haven't found anywhere that lists much of what I want to know, which led to my confusion above. For example, I know that g addresses the entire file, and ^ goes to the first nonblank character in the line, but I don't know what / does and I'm never sure if ' is being used as a single quote or as an operator. Could you help me with this?