# BASH - Tell if duplicate lines exist (y/n)

Tags: bash, file, uniq

I am writing a script to manipulate a text file.

First thing I want to do is check if duplicate entries exist and if so, ask the user whether we wants to keep or remove them.

I know how to display duplicate lines if they exist, but what I want to learn is just to get a yes/no answer to the question "Do duplicates exist?"

It seems `uniq` will return `0` either if duplicates were found or not as long as the command completed without issues.

What is that command that I can put in an `if`-statement just to tell me if duplicate lines exist?

My file is very simple, it is just values in single column.

Comment: If you're not against using Vim to filter text files manually, I recommend the `HighlightRepeats` method in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268032. I often use it to filter duplicate files/folders, then apply shell commands on the filtered file.

Comment: @F.X Thanks for your reply. I would like to accomplish this with some lines within my script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `awk` combined with the boolean `||` operator:

```
# Ask question if awk found a duplicate
awk 'a[$0]++{exit 1}' test.txt || (
    echo -n "remove duplicates? [y/n] "
    read answer
    # Remove duplicates if answer was "y" . I'm using `[` the shorthand
    # of the test command. Check `help [`
    [ "$answer" == "y" ] && uniq test.txt > test.uniq.txt
)
```

The block after the `||` will only get executed if the awk command returns 1, meaning it found duplicates.

However, for a basic understanding I'll also show an example using an `if` block

```
awk 'a[$0]++{exit 1}' test.txt

# $? contains the return value of the last command
if [ $? != 0 ] ; then
    echo -n "remove duplicates? [y/n] "
    read answer
    # check answer
    if [ "$answer" == "y" ] ; then
        uniq test.txt > test.uniq.txt            
    fi
fi
```

However the `[]` are **not** just *brackets* like in other programming languages. `[` is a synonym for the `test` bash builtin command and `]` it's last argument. You need to read `help [` in order to understand

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will give a try to your code.

Answer (score 10):

I'd probably use `awk` to do this but, for the sake of variety, here is a brief pipe to accomplish the same thing:

```
$ { sort | uniq -d | grep . -qc; } < noduplicates.txt; echo $?
1
$ { sort | uniq -d | grep . -qc; } < duplicates.txt; echo $?
0
```

`sort` + `uniq -d` make sure that only duplicate lines (which don't have to be adjacent) get printed to `stdout` and `grep . -c` counts those lines emulating `wc -l` with the useful side effect that it returns `1` if it doesn't match (i.e. a zero count) and `-q` just silents the output so it doesn't print the line count so you can use it silently in your script.

```
has_duplicates()
{
  {
    sort | uniq -d | grep . -qc
  } < "$1"
}

if has_duplicates myfile.txt; then
  echo "myfile.txt has duplicate lines"
else
  echo "myfile.txt has no duplicate lines"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do `uniq=yes/no` using this awk one-liner:

```
awk '!seen[$0]{seen[$0]++; i++} END{print (NR>i)?"no":"yes"}' file
```

- awk uses an array of uniques called `seen`.
- Every time we put an element in unique we increment an counter `i++`.
- Finally in `END` block we compare # of records with unique # of records in this code: `(NR>i)?`
- If condition is true that means there are duplicate records and we print `no` otherwise it prints `yes`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you please explain to me how your line works?

Comment: Yes sure added explanation.

Answer (score 1):

A quick bash solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

INPUT_FILE=words

declare -A a 
while read line ; do
    [ "${a[$line]}" = 'nonempty' ] && duplicates=yes && break
    a[$line]=nonempty
done < $INPUT_FILE

[ "$duplicates" = yes ] && echo -n "Keep duplicates? [Y/n]" && read keepDuplicates

removeDuplicates() {
    sort -u $INPUT_FILE > $INPUT_FILE.tmp
    mv $INPUT_FILE.tmp $INPUT_FILE
}

[ "$keepDuplicates" != "Y" ] && removeDuplicates
```

The script reads line by line from the INPUT_FILE and stores each line in the associative array `a` as the key and sets the string `nonempty` as value. Before storing the value, it first checks whether it is already there - if it is it means it found a duplicate and it  sets the `duplicates` flag and then it breaks out of the cycle.

Later it only checks if the flag is set and asks the user whether to keep the duplicates. If they answer anything else than `Y` then it calls the `removeDuplicates` function which uses `sort -u` to remove the duplicates. `${a[$line]}` evaluates to the value of the associative array `a` for the key `$line`. `[ "$duplicates" = yes ]` is a bash builtin syntax for a test. If the test succeeds then whatever follows after `&&` is evaluated.

But note that the awk solutions will likely be faster so you may want to use them if you expect to process bigger files.

Comment: Thanks jkbkot! Can you please give me a brief explanation of how this code works? I am a rookie :)

Comment: @DMS no problem, added explanation. Btw, upvoting is good enough as thanks ;) also, try to accept one of the answers to keep the site organized. Happy coding!