# mark duplicate lines and exclude characters from the results

Tags: vim, duplicates, vim-syntax-highlighting

I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268032/marking-duplicate-lines) one-liner to find duplicate lines in a text file:

```
:syn clear Repeat | g/^\(.*\)\n\ze\%(.*\n\)*\1$/exe 'syn match Repeat "^' . escape(getline('.'), '".\^$*[]') . '$"' | nohlsearch
```

When I execute it on `C` source files, it correctly returns so many `{` and `break;` and empty lines. However, they are not the most interesting lines. Howe I can exclude one or multiple characters from the result of this one-liner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow that was hard.
But i think i got it:

```
:syn clear Repeat | g/^\(^\(\(\s*break\;\|\s*{\|\s*}\)\@!.\).*\)\n\ze\%(.*\n\)*\1$/exe 'syn match Repeat "^' . escape(getline('.'), '".\^$*[]') . '$"' | nohlsearch
```

It ignores the following 3 patterns:

```
\s*break;
\s*}
\s*{
```

You can ad more in the list separated by `\|`.

As you can easily spot, it isn't really a nice readable solution. You could improve it with the `very magic mode see :h \v`. But why do you even need the test for 2 same lines? maybe there is a better solution for your whole usecase